# C++ [linker error] undefined reference to operator= to sort vector of tuple

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, linker

I have an abstract class with some method and attribute in A.h

```
class A
{
public:
    ...
    virtual A& operator =(const A& init) = 0;
    ....
};
```

and its specification in B.h

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    ...
    A& operator =(const A& init);
    ....
};
```

and its definition in B.cpp. Try in main to sort vector of tuple

```
std::vector < std::tuple < B, double> > b;
```

Then I try to sort it

```
std::sort(b.begin(), b.end(),[](std::tuple<B, double> const &t1, std::tuple<B, double> const &t2) {return std::get<1>(t1) < std::get<1>(t2);});
```

But problem at linking undefined reference to A::operator=(A const&)

Could anyone explain me what or where is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does this actually compile? `class B :: public A`

Comment: mistake sorry class B : class A

Comment: You can edit your question and fix that.

Comment: solved by defining both A& operator=(const A&) and B& operator=(const B&). I'm not sure that it is clean code so in case of others "cleaner solutions"  ..